# Code Formatting

Tags: apex, ide, code, eclipse

Has anyone gotten code formatting (Ctrl+Shift+F) to work in Eclipse? I know it's basically a Java feature but it would be neat to format Apex code according to rules.

I also can't get some hotkeys like "Insert Block Comment" to work - any specialities there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code formatting (as well as some of the other common Java features) is not supported in the Force.com IDE, unfortunately.

At one point I looked into adding some of the features I miss from Javaland, and determined it wouldn't be tons of work (the Eclipse API is very well documented) but too much time to justify for purely personal use.

Comment: Would a 3rd party plugin work in Apex?

Comment: It would be in Eclipse, not in Apex per se, so yes. Eclipse is designed with an open plugin architecture. At worst it would require implementing a new type of Editor from scratch that implemented the features you wanted. Still, not worth the individual effort IMO. You may also want to take a look at BrainEngine.

Comment: Thanks for the BrainEngine tip! Eclipse is driving me crazy and I'm ready to pay good money for something productive!

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported out of the gate with the Force.com IDE. If you would like it to be supported, I would suggest voting on it in Ideas - http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006rPZAAY

Although I have no personally gotten this working, this Community post - http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Formatting-code-in-Eclipse/td-p/85164 - suggests checking out this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801064/how-can-do-code-alignment-in-eclipse-base-force-com-ide/8811156#8811156

Hopefully some of that can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

No. Coding formatting (Ctrl+Shift+F)  is not supported by force.com eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I use both Eclipse and MavensMate plugin and I'm not endorsing either. You might also want to look at the [MavensMate plugin](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText) if you use SublimeText

It provides code formatting as well as a number of other interesting features.

Comment: Obviously I would want something which works in Eclipse :-) Most IDEs allow you to run external .exes (e.g. JSHint) on your source. I might follow that up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MavensMate does not provide code formatting. It can do Apex language auto-completions, but does not provide reformatting or auto-indenting capabilities for Apex.